# WebSQL/SQLite order by javascript date obj

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a html5/jqm/phonegap application. I'm selecting a list of records from a client-side db table. I want to group and order them by date but the date that exists in the table is a JS date object like:

```
Mon Nov 19 2012 16:20:55 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

I want to group and order them by the numerical day (18,19,20 in this example). So the following details:

```
Sun Nov 18 2012 16:20:55 GMT+0000 (GMT)
Mon Nov 19 2012 16:20:55 GMT+0000 (GMT)
Sun Nov 18 2012 16:20:55 GMT+0000 (GMT)
Tue Nov 12 2012 16:20:55 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

Would be returned in this order:

```
Tue Nov 20 2012 16:20:55 GMT+0000 (GMT)
Mon Nov 19 2012 16:20:55 GMT+0000 (GMT)
Sun Nov 18 2012 16:20:55 GMT+0000 (GMT)
Sun Nov 18 2012 16:20:55 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

Is it possible to do this in sql as part of the select? Or if not could someone piont me in the right direction on how to do this within Js/jQuery?

Thanks in advance

** Edit in response to questions from Pete **

I'm using the Jaascript/html5 client side version of SQL, which I believe is based on SQLite. To create the DB I'm just calling the following js -

```
var db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
```

My Db schema is :

```
transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE RECORDINGS (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, caseRef, startDate, endDate, caseTypeId, actionTypeId, notes, userId, syncStatus);');
transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO RECORDINGS (caseRef, startDate, endDate, caseTypeId, actionTypeId, notes, userId, syncStatus) VALUES ("CR1234", "'+startDate+'", "'+endDate+'", 1, 2, "Meeting about something", 1, 0);');
```

My select currently looks like:

```
function getRecordingsQuery(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('SELECT RECORDINGS.id, RECORDINGS.caseRef, RECORDINGS.startDate, RECORDINGS.endDate, RECORDINGS.notes, RECORDINGS.syncStatus, CASETYPES.description FROM RECORDINGS, CASETYPES WHERE RECORDINGS.caseTypeId = CASETYPES.id AND RECORDINGS.userId =? ORDER BY startDate DESC', [window.currentSignedInUserId], getRecordingsDataHandler, errorHandler);
    }
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

SQLLite does not support `DATEPART`, but it does support `strftime`. Try adding the following as your `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY CAST(strftime("%d", date) AS INTEGER) DESC
```

You could instead process the sort in JavaScript. I'm sure there are better, or more efficient ways to do this, but you could just use the built-in sort for arrays like so:

```
var getRecordingsDataHandler = function getRecordingsDataHandler(tx, results) {
    var rows = [],
        row = null,
        i = 0;
      if (results.rows && results.rows.length) {
        for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i += 1) {
            rows.push({
                "startDate": new Date(results.rows.item(i).startDate),
                "data": results.rows.item(i)
            });
        }
        rows.sort(function (a, b) {
            var ascending = a.startDate.getDate() - b.startDate.getDate(),
                descending = b.startDate.getDate() - a.startDate.getDate();
            return descending;
        });
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i += 1) {
            row = rows[i].data;
            //process the rest
            //since row === results.rows.item(i), reference from row
        }
    }
};
```

**ORIGINAL:**

Without knowing what SQL version you are using, it's harder to answer that portion of your question. I think most of them support a `DATEPART` function, so you could try:

```
ORDER BY DATEPART(dd, YourDateField) DESC
```

As far as JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var d = new Date('Tue Nov 20 2012 16:20:55 GMT+0000 (GMT)');
```

will return a date object in JavaScript which you can then sort by. For just the date:

```
d.getDate(); //returns day of month
```

If you can be a little more specific in your question (which engine/version of SQL you are using, or how your client-side table is structured and the function you are using to sort it), then we may be able to assist you a little better.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - I've edited the question with the details you asked for (or as much as I can). Does this help?